# Why is my graphics card not detected the first time I start the PC?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, hardware-detection

I just upgraded to a *Palit GeForce GTX 650 Ti 2GB RAM* and I'm experiencing a problem with it. The system takes slightly longer to display the BIOS splash screen and the graphics card goes into some sort of a safe mode when PC is *turned on*. So if I just turn on my computer windows will act as if the card is unknown generic type and try to reinstall the drivers and prompt for system reset; ubuntu crashes while loading (blinking marker for too long). If I restart the computer pretty much at any point afar the BIOS splash screen (the first time it is turned on) -- I usually do it after the GRUB screen appears -- without even getting in an OS the card works normally. I just bought a new more powerful PSU (Alpine 700W with a 6-pin connector). The problem shouldn't be OS-related as it also occurs on Ubuntu, but you never know. I have the latest Nvidia drivers installed. I have set the initialise first to PEG in the BIOS. I also updated to the latest version of BIOS (motherboard GA-EP35-DS3). Any other possible reasons for that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't your BIOS have a setting to determine which display to initialise first? Many BIOSes have a setting, commonly with the options "Onboard", "PCI" and "PCIEx". You'd want the latter. Perhaps you can even disable onboard graphics entirely.

If not, there also used to be a setting to introduce a small delay in the POST (Power On Self Test), which was intended to allow hard disks an extra second or so to initialise so they could be detected properly. It is doubtful, but your BIOS might still have such a setting.

I don't think the power supply is really to blame here, but you could try it with another to see if the card does get sufficient power fast enough.

You may want to see if there are any BIOS updates for your motherboard or even the graphics card as well as try the card in another system.

Comment: I had set the initialise first to PEG. I also have no POST feature in the BIOS. Is the BIOS to blame? I had a PCIe graphics card (Nvidia 9400 GT) and it had no such problems.

Comment: The BIOS POST is a process, not a feature you find in the setup screens. It can be the BIOS' 'fault' if it doesn't allow a reasonable time for the hardware to initialise.

The delay I'm referring to is called "Hard Disk Pre-Delay" or "HDD DELAY", but as it's intended for hard drives, it may not take place at the appropriate time during the POST and is a long shot at best.